# How can i valid the data of an ag-grid cell?

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

I want to validate the cell, when the number will be different than 9 i want to change the background

I have this table:

```
{
 cellEditor: 'numberRenderer',
 width: 150,
 cellClass: this.compareValues,
 newValueHandler: this.compareValues,
 cellEditorParams: {
 required: true,
},

compareValues(params) {
        return params.value === 9?'':'myClass';
      },
.myClass
    background: var(--ag-header-background-color, #222628)
```

but when i put the number 9 i dont see the change of style, what is the problem?

Comment: there is two possibilities 
First is your condition value not matching or
second is your style is not well formated

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure if you are doing type comparison with equality comparator then  both side are of same type `params.documentId === 9?'':'myClass';` this will only work when `params.documentId` is a number else it will always be false. either change `===` to `==` comparison or make sure the types are same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `cellStyle`

```
{
 cellEditor: 'numberRenderer',
 cellStyle: function (params) {
   if(params.value !==9){
         setTimeout(() => {
                params.api.refreshCells({
                    force: true,
                    rowNodes: [params.api.node], 
                });
            }, 10000);
      return {background: 'red'};
      }
    }
  }
```

## Try to refresh :-

```
params.api.refreshCells({
             force: true,
             rowNodes: [params.api.node]
   });
```

Comment: Updated answer, try to refresh  as above in your code.